# New added row on button is not working in second row

Tags: javascript, html

I have nested tables parent and child table. Both tables can add rows on button click if needed. Problem i am facing is this when a row is added in parent table then in that row child table button not works. they work fine for child table of first row in parent table and not works for the second row. please see snippet for demonstration.

```js
  function addRow(tableID) {

      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

      var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

      var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

      for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
          case "text":
              newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
              break;
          case "checkbox":
              newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
              break;
          case "select-one":
              newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
              break;
        }
      }
    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
      try {
      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;

      for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
          if(rowCount <= 1) {
            alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
            break;
          }
          table.deleteRow(i);
          rowCount--;
          i--;
        }


      }
      }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
      }
    }
    
     function addRow1(tableID) {

      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

      var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

      var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

      for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
          case "text":
              newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
              break;
          case "checkbox":
              newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
              break;
          case "select-one":
              newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
              break;
        }
      }
    }

    function deleteRow1(tableID) {
      try {
      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;

      for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
          if(rowCount <= 1) {
            alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
            break;
          }
          table.deleteRow(i);
          rowCount--;
          i--;
        }


      }
      }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
      }
    }
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid #1E90FF;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    border:1px solid #1E90FF;

}



th {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
 <TABLE id="dataTable">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                  <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Select&nbsp;</th>    
                  <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<b>Size</b>&nbsp;</th>
                  <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<b>Color & Quantity</b>&nbsp;</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  
                  <tbody>
                  <tr id='C1' class='customer'>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
                  <td><select  name="size[]" id="size" required="" >
                  <option value="">Select Size</option></select></td>
                  <td>

                  <TABLE style="margin-top: 20px;" id="dataTable1" width="400px" border="1">
                  <thead>
                  <th>&nbsp;Select&nbsp;</th>    
                  <th>&nbsp;<b>Color&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Quantity</b>&nbsp;</th>  
                  </thead> 
                  <TR>
                  <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
                  <TD>
                  <select name="color[]" required="" >
                    <option value="">Select Color</option>
                    <option value="Red">Red</option>
                     <option value="Green">Green</option>  
                      <option value="Blue">Blue</option>  
                       <option value="Black">Black</option>  
                    
                  </select>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <input type="number" name="dress_quantity[]" class="qty1" placeholder="Size Quantity" value="" required="">  
                  </TD>
                  </TR>
                  </TABLE>
                  
                  <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow1('dataTable1')" />
                  <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow1('dataTable1')" />
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  </TABLE>
                  <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
                  <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

You are copying/cloning the HTML of parent to child rows and this in-turns assigns parent id (of first row based on your code) to child rows.

Code causing issue in `addRow` method:

`newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;`

**Solution:**

Assign different id's to the new child table and buttons when you click on parent's `Add Row` button.

Replace the below line in `addRow` method from:

`newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;`

to

```
if (i == colCount - 1) //last column which adds child table
{
    //Get child table id of first row
    var tableID = table.rows[1].cells[i].childNodes[1].getAttribute("id"); 

    //Replace all occurances of parent table id's with new unique table id for child table before writing the information to DOM
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(tableID,"g"), "dataTable" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1));
}
else  //For other columns there is no need to assign unique id for controls
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
```

**Note:** I am generating random number using `Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1))`. You may want to change to logic of your own.

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

 var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

 for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
  var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

  if (i == colCount - 1) //last column
  {
   //Get child table id of first row
   var tableID = table.rows[1].cells[i].childNodes[1].getAttribute("id"); 
   newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(tableID,"g"), "dataTable" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1));
  }
  else
   newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;

  //alert(newcell.childNodes);
  switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
   case "text":
    newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
    break;
   case "checkbox":
    newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
    break;
   case "select-one":
    newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
    break;
  }
 }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
 try {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
   var row = table.rows[i];
   var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
   if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
    if (rowCount <= 1) {
     alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
     break;
    }
    table.deleteRow(i);
    rowCount--;
    i--;
   }
  }
 } catch (e) {
  alert(e);
 }
}

function addRow1(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

 for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {

  var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

  newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
  //alert(newcell.childNodes);
  switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
   case "text":
    newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
    break;
   case "checkbox":
    newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
    break;
   case "select-one":
    newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
    break;
  }
 }
}

function deleteRow1(tableID) {
 try {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
   var row = table.rows[i];
   var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
   if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
    if (rowCount <= 1) {
     alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
     break;
    }
    table.deleteRow(i);
    rowCount--;
    i--;
   }
  }
 } catch (e) {
  alert(e);
 }
}
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #1E90FF;
 }

 th,
 td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #1E90FF;
 }

 th {
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  color: white;
 }
</style>

<TABLE id="dataTable">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Select&nbsp;</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<b>Size</b>&nbsp;</th>
   <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<b>Color & Quantity</b>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
  <tr id='C1' class='customer'>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" /></td>
   <td><select name="size[]" id="size" required="">
     <option value="">Select Size</option></select></td>
   <td>
    <TABLE style="margin-top: 20px;" id="dataTable1" width="400px" border="1">
     <thead>
      <th>&nbsp;Select&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;<b>Color&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Quantity</b>&nbsp;</th>
     </thead>
     <TR>
      <TD>
       <INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" />
      </TD>
      <TD>
       <select name="color[]" required="">
        <option value="">Select Color</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Green">Green</option>  
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>  
        <option value="Black">Black</option>  
       </select> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <input type="number" name="dress_quantity[]" class="qty1" placeholder="Size Quantity" value="" required="">
      </TD>
     </TR>
    </TABLE>

    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow1('dataTable1')" />
    <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow1('dataTable1')" />
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</TABLE>

<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
```

Comment: You can check the running example above.

Comment: Thanks alot @Phani Kumar M

Comment: If i had 2 rows for color in first row then in new row it copies two rows for color. can it be possible that when new row is added in parent table it always copies only one row for color not all rows from previous?

Comment: Not possible with your current implementation. Only solution is to make first row fixed i.e. no Add/Delete buttons for child table. You should also prevent users from deleting first row.

Comment: is there any running example i can see? any link?